# C++ array_put()

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello i have question about C++ infinity arrays. Does this array_put() function by creating new array is best way to increase array size? Maybe there are faster ways than this? :(

Here whot i using and unsure about this...

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// ============================================================
//                       ALERT WINDOW
// ============================================================
void alert(string value, string title = "Warning")
{
    MessageBox(NULL, value.c_str(), title.c_str(), MB_OK);
}
// ============================================================


// ============================================================
//                     INTEGER TO STRING
// ============================================================
string integer_to_string(int value)
{
    ostringstream stream;
    stream<<value<<flush;

    return stream.str();
}
// ============================================================

// ============================================================
//                          ARRAY PUT
// ============================================================
typedef struct ARRAY{
    int* data;
    int length = 0;
} array;

void array_put(array &array_data, int value)
{
    int* new_array = new int[array_data.length+1];
    if (array_data.length != 0){new_array = array_data.data;}

    new_array[array_data.length] = value;

    array_data.data = new_array; array_data.length++;
}
// ============================================================


// ============================================================
//                ARRAY PRINT (REQ: ARRAY PUT)
// ============================================================
string array_print(array array_data)
{
    string out = "";
    out += "array_length: " + integer_to_string(array_data.length) + "\n";
    for (int i=0;i < array_data.length;i++)
    {
        out += "[" + integer_to_string(i) + "] = " + integer_to_string(array_data.data[i]) + "\n";
    }
    return out;
}
// ============================================================

int main()
{
    array array_data;
    array_put(array_data, 120);
    array_put(array_data, 170);

    string result = array_print(array_data);
    alert(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could look into using a std::vector, which would automatically (or manually) handle reallocation if greater size was needed.

Answer (score 1):

Others already have pointed out the errors in your code, and pointed you to the fact that you probably should use `vector` instead of a home-grown solution. However nobody has yet addressed your actual question whether there's a faster method.

Assuming you typically add more than one element to the same array, this is indeed not optimal: As is (after correcting the errors), you'll reallocate the array for every single additional entry, complete with copying all the data previously stored. Since that data will grow with every element, you get quadratic complexity of insertions (the number of copies that have to be made is proportional to the square of the number of elements you insert), and a linear number of expensive reallocations.

A better strategy is to always allocate a certain fraction of the number of existing elements as new elements, and keeping track of how many of those elements are actually part of the array, and how many are just already preallocated for adding new elements later. That reduces the number of reallocations the more, the larger your array already is, and ultimately gives you an amortized constant complexity (on average, the number of copies to perform is proportional to the number of elements you insert), and a logarithmic number of expensive reallocations.

Indeed, that is exactly what `vector` does.

Answer (score 0):

Function array_put is simply invalid. For example there is a memory leak in your function. At first you allocated memory and assigned its address to new_array and in the next statement you reassigned new_array. So the address of the allocated memory was lost.

I think that instead of this

```
void array_put(array &array_data, int value)
{
int* new_array = new int[array_data.length+1];
 if (array_data.length != 0){new_array = array_data.data;}

new_array[array_data.length] = value;

array_data.data = new_array; array_data.length++;
}
```

you meant the following

```
void array_put( array &array_data, int value )
{
    int *data  = new int[array_data.length+1];

    std::copy( array_data.data, array_data.data + array_data.length, data );
    data[array_data.length] = value;

    delete [] array_data.data;

    array_data.data = data;
    ++array_data.length; 
}
```

Of course it would be better if you would use standard class `std::vector` instead of manually allocating an array.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code. First of all

```
new_array = array_data.data;
```

does not copy the content of the old array to the new array, it just assigns the pointer, so after that new_array is the same as array_data.data. You could use memcpy here:

```
memcpy(new_array, array_data.data, sizeof(int)*array_data.length);
```

You also need to free the old array data before asigning the new storage to avoid leaks, so:

```
delete [] array_data.data;
array_data.data = new_array;
```

After you make your code to work correctly, you can think about allocating more storage to avoid allocating new array in every array_put.

Answer (score 0):

Quite apart from your solution not working, increasing the size by 1 each time means that adding N items will require O(N * N) copies - you copy 1 item, then 2, then 3, and so on.

Just use `vector`. It works, and it is guaranteed to add an element in constant time on average.